# Is it possible to upload/move files into list that doesn't currently store files?

Tags: custom-list, file-upload

We have a (custom) list of data, but I'd like to upload files for some of the entries there.

Is it possible in SP/SPD to adapt or convert the list to accept files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is Attachments.

To attach a file to a list item, you can either select an item in the list view, and click on the "Attach File" ribbon button in the "Items" tab, or edit the item and click on "Attach File" in the Edit ribbon.

If you do not see those buttons in the ribbon, attachments may be disabled for the list.  In order to enable attachments, go to the List Settings page, and click on "Advanced Settings", there should be an option to enable attachments for the list there.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. I can do that, although I'm hoping to get the files visible so they show in the page list web part (with icon), and over time it will be more of a document library that a list. Any other workaround do you think?

Comment: You can add the "Attachment" column to the list view so you can see with an icon which list items have files attached, and of course you can put that as one of the first columns in the view so the icon will be over on the left.  Converting to a Doc Lib is difficult - you would have to create a new Doc Lib, add all the columns you have in your list, and then copy all the items over (maybe with Powershell?).  In addition, with a Doc Lib, *every* item would *require* a document, you would not be able to have any items without a document.

Comment: Yep, the attachment icon is there, but of course it just indicates that there is a file if you click into the record. I think I'll kick off a new document library. Useful advice on attachment, though, thanks a lot.